# How to configure ssl_prefer_server_ciphers in NGINX Ingress Controller?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I need to set `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers` to `on` in NGINX Ingress Controller.

Unfortunately, I was not able to find how to do it in its configuration
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/

What is the default value of `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers` in NGINX Ingress Controller?

(the default in NGINX is `off`)

Hot to set the value to `on` in NGINX Ingress Controller?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/

```
In order to overwrite nginx-controller configuration values as seen in config.go, you can add key-value pairs to the data section of the config-map.
```

Therefore, the configuration is

```
data:
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers: "on"
```